# Column Summation of Cell Labels Excel

Tags: excel, sum

I have (sparse) data (in the first few cells for example where PA is A1 etc). The labels are fixed but the numbers need to be arbitrary\variable.

```
PA  5       8               
RA      7   2.55        11      7.1
Pils        8           4.5 6.4 
S\P     4   3.5 4.2 5.2     7.2
    GH  ED  CW  TR  PH  FL  DG
```

Now I want to add up some of these entries. I want to add up all combinations under the following rule:

1. There should be one element from each row
2. There should be at most one element from each column

In this example I was able to do this by hand and the cells I want to add up (vertically) are as follows (this data is sitting in the four rows of cells below cells from B7 to AV7 inclusive):

```
B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1
C2  C2  C2  C2  C2  C2  D2  D2  D2  D2
F3  F3  F3  G3  G3  G3  C3  C3  C3  F3
D4  E4  H4  D4  F4  H4  E4  F4  H4  C4

******************************************************************************

B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1
D2  D2  D2  D2  D2  D2  F2  F2  F2  F2
F3  F3  G3  G3  G3  G3  C3  C3  C3  G3
E4  H4  C4  E4  F4  H4  D4  E4  H4  C4

******************************************************************************

B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1  B1
F2  F2  F2  H2  H2  H2  H2  H2  H2  H2
G3  G3  G3  C3  C3  F3  F3  F3  G3  G3
D4  E4  H4  D4  E4  C4  D4  E4  C4  D4


******************************************************************************

B1  B1  D1  D1  D1  D1  D1  D1  D1  D1
H2  H2  C2  C2  C2  C2  F2  F2  F2  F2
G3  G3  F3  F3  G3  G3  C3  C3  G3  G3
E4  F4  E4  H4  F4  H4  E4  H4  C4  E4

******************************************************************************
D1  D1  D1  D1  D1  D1  D1
F2  H2  H2  H2  H2  H2  H2
G3  C3  F3  F3  G3  G3  G3
H4  E4  C4  E4  C4  E4  F4


******************************************************************************
```

Frankly I am stumped. I thought I could do stuff like =(=B7) and such but it isn't working. I would have tried some IF stuff but since the state space was so small I thought it might have been easier to write out all the combinations.

I need to send the worksheet to someone who will input the data and find the minimum of the 47 combinations.

Thank you for your time. I have a basic, working use of Excel.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow but, if it helps at all, the equivalent of what you are trying with `=(=B7)` would be `=INDIRECT(B7)`. That is, get the value that B7 refers to.

Comment: If you wanna throw it down as an answer I will accept.

Comment: @pnuts Thank you but I was able to do =Sum(Indirect(B7):Indirect(B10)) etc

Comment: @pnuts The blanks are non-options. By the way the vertical labels are four types of beers, and the horizontal labels are different breweries. For a beer tasting I want a beer of each type from distinct breweries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of what you are trying with `=(=B7)` would be `=INDIRECT(B7)`. That is, get the value that B7 refers to.